# Upgrade from Django 1.6 to 1.7 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

I tried to upgrade django from version 1.6.5 to 1.7 through `pip` and `easy_install` but it does not work :

```
$ pip2.7 install --upgrade django
Requirement already up-to-date: django in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
```

Apart from installing django from the source, is there another way to force the upgrade ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django 1.7 hasn't been released yet, so no.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was already released because the bottom right links on [docs.djangoproject.com](http://docs.djangoproject.com) say 1.6-->1.7-->dev